# Firebase Log-in events

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to see Who and When login to the Firebase from UI side, as administrator.
It is not related data access from app etc.
So, I login to https://firebase.google.com/ as User/Manager/Admin and want to see it in logs.
It should be in GCP project related to firebase, if so how can I find it - did saw in Log explorer.
Or it should be in Firebase UI?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a *workaround*. You can use [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects) which is in *beta*.

Consider you have to watch a project.

You can make a request like below to get the Project Details.

```http
GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{YourProjectID}
```

Sample Response:

```json
{
  "projectId": "*****************",
  "projectNumber": "*****************",
  "displayName": "Sample App",
  "name": "projects/*****************",
  "resources": {
    "hostingSite": "*****************",
    "realtimeDatabaseInstance": "*****************"
  },
  "state": "ACTIVE",
  "etag": "1_d15ff4d3-727e-431c-8eba-f33957805f23"
}
```

In the response, you have a key called `ETAG`. Basically, this changes whenever the project is opened by someone.

You cannot get who is logged-in or other details.
You can only know someone has opened, changed or made some operations in the project, using `ETAG`.

You can simply store the `ETAG` in your server and poll for the change.
If it is changed, then someone might have used the Project.

If you want the *Updated Time* of the project along with it, you can try this,
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/get